# Replace Substring in Specific Key Value of an Array

Tags: javascript

I have an array & I am trying to replace a substring of a particular key's value w/ another substring.

Example key:value

```
var myobj = {};    
key1: "FieldName[8] = \"field9\";"
```

I was trying to change the [8] to [9]

```
var kstr = '[' + k + ']'; // [8]
var dbstr = '[' + dbindex + ']'; // [9]
myobj[key1].replace(kstr, dbstr);
console.log('Key1: ' + myobj[key1]) // Still has [8] in it !
```

Comment: does the value of `myobj[key1]`  is `"FieldName[8] = \"field9\";"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the MDN documentation for [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) states:

> Note: The original string will remain unchanged.

So, you need to assign the result of the `replace()` operation back to the variable:

```
myobj[key1] = myobj[key1].replace(kstr, dbstr);
```